# Render 2D floor plan on Android using openGl

Tags: android, opengl-es

I am looking to create a floor plan as show in the image below on android.

[image]

My Question how can this be done in openGL or should I just use the image?, I only looked at openGL and managed to create a square :) on the android screen. Is there any software that I can use to plot the points or how would I go about doing this?

Comment: Are you looking to make this 3d?  I'm not sure you even need opengl.  I would look at http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/2d-graphics.html and http://developer.android.com/training/custom-views/custom-drawing.html

Comment: no, 2d will be fine. I just thought that by using opengl the app would perform faster.

Comment: use an old good Canvas API then

Comment: basically its for an indoor navigation application and there will be alot of other stuff going on in the background, calculating current location and destination etc etc.. I was thinking If I done it in openGL I could save on performance?

Comment: are you gonna move over that building sitting on the space rocket? if not, simple View with a Canvas or SurfaceView would be enough ;)

Comment: @pskink LOL, ok I hear you and Canvas will give me coordinates and I can overlay it with location icon and destination icon?

Comment: uhm, Canvas API is good enough to do that in a easy way, see how to implement a custom View

Comment: Hello Gman. Do you have results with you questin? How have you solved it? Canvas was the issue or you used OpenGL ?