# overlay canvas image with another image android

Tags: android, canvas

I have an image of a floor plan displayed on screen, My Question how do I overlay another image on that.

see the image from another thread where I asked a how to [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27733276/render-2d-floor-plan-on-android-using-opengl?noredirect=1#comment43878766_27733276)

```
/**
 * floor plan drawing.
 *
 * @param canvas the canvas on which the background will be drawn
 */
@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    Bitmap temp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.floorplan);
    image= Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(temp, canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight(), true);
    canvas.drawBitmap(image, 0, 0, null);

}
```

Comment: first: onDraw is not the best place to `BitmapFactory.decodeResource()`, second: instead of calling `Bitmap.createScaledBitmap()` modify the `canvas` (scale, translate, rotate)

Comment: @pskink ok, what show only be in Draw?

Comment: In onDraw call only canvas related stuff,  i think your IDE warns you about calling decodeResource and like stuff

Comment: @pskink ok but it not let me take image = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(temp, canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight(), true); out?

Comment: ??? What do you mean?

Comment: when I try to take bitmap.createScaledBitmap out from onDraw it give error, Cannot resolve symbol canvas. where should I put it? I do get what your saying but not sure where to place createScaledBitmap.

Comment: You should not use scaled Bitmap: scale the Canvas instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about adding the second image over the first one?

```
@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas)
{
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    Bitmap temp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.floorplan);
    image = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(temp, canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight(), true);
    canvas.drawBitmap(image, 0, 0, null);

    Bitmap over = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.overlay);
    image = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(over, canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight(), true);
    canvas.drawBitmap(image, 0, 0, null);
}
```

Comment: very very slow if you are overlaying 500+ images

Comment: Sorry but I am handling 900 images :) and I did make it fast :)

Comment: Well, for the OP purposes (overlay 2 images), this is fast enough. Any way I'd be intrested in knowing why you want to overlay so many images. And it would be nice to see your lightspeed code, as well.

Comment: Actually I need to overlay some images on videos .. For this I have used ffmpeg lib for converting vdo to the frames so for 60 sec video it will make 900 frames as 15frames/sec ...so after processing all images in to the folder i will pick images from the folder n overlay on that :P :)
and for making it fast processing I have converted my images 32 bit to 8 bit before overlying.

Comment: I see. But for a couple of static images (say a background image and a conditionally changing foreground icon), I can be happy with my code. ;)

Answer (score 0):

This is my method, to overlay two images into an ImageView:

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

Using this method:

```
  public static Bitmap overlayBitmap(Bitmap bitmapBackground, Bitmap bitmapImage) {

        int bitmap1Width = bitmapBackground.getWidth();
        int bitmap1Height = bitmapBackground.getHeight();
        int bitmap2Width = bitmapImage.getWidth();
        int bitmap2Height = bitmapImage.getHeight();

        float marginLeft = (float) (bitmap1Width * 0.5 - bitmap2Width * 0.5);
        float marginTop = (float) (bitmap1Height * 0.5 - bitmap2Height * 0.5);

        Bitmap overlayBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap1Width, bitmap1Height, bitmapBackground.getConfig());
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(overlayBitmap);
        canvas.drawBitmap(bitmapBackground, new Matrix(), null);
        canvas.drawBitmap(bitmapImage, marginLeft, marginTop, null);

        return overlayBitmap;
    }
```

get the references and bitmaps to make de overlay!

```
   ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);

    Bitmap background = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.background);
    Bitmap image = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.androide);

    Bitmap bmpImages = overlayBitmap(background, image);
    imageView.setImageBitmap(bmpImages);
```

to have this as a result:

[image]

[**Download the complete sample.**](https://github.com/Jorgesys/Android-Overlay-Images)